# Matching exactly one occurrence in a string with a regular expression

Tags: regex

The other day I sat with a regular expression problem. Eventually I solved it a different way, without regular expressions, but I would still like to know how you do it :)

The problem I was having was running svn update via an automated script, and I wanted to detect conflicts. Doing this with or without regex is trivial, but it got me thinking about a more obscure problem: How do you match exactly ONE occurrence of a character inside a fixed length field of whitespace?

For instance, let's say we wanted to match "C" inside a six-byte wide field:

```
"C     " MATCH
"   C  " MATCH
" C C  " NO MATCH
"  M   " NO MATCH
"      " NO MATCH
"C      " NO MATCH (7 characters, not 6)
"   C " NO MATCH (5 characters, not 6)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's not right to answer your own question, but I basically merged your answers ... please don't flame :)

`^(?=.{6}$) *C *$`

Edit:
Replacing . with Tomalak's response below [ C] increases the speed with about 4-5% or so

`^(?=[ C]{6}$) *C *$`

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's good, too. The final `$` still is unnecessary, see my note #2. *(And no, there is noting wrong with answering your own question at all. No danger of being flamed.)*

Comment: @tomalak if I remove the final $, it fails when something other than C occures after the C, and also on multiple occurences of C

Comment: See my changed answer for an initial look-ahead that fixes this.

Comment: I've just done some benchmarking, this is by far the fastest variant: `^(?=[ C]{6}$) *C *`. A little slower is the look-ahead based version from my answer `^(?=[ C]{6}$) *C(?! *C)`, and @Gumbo's two monster regexes are from the comments to @eumiro's answer are the slowest of the bunch, the second one slightly faster than the first one.

Comment: @Tomalak - did you use spaces instead of `[^C]` on Gumbo's regex? While we're being silly, you might as well test `C-----|-C----|--C---|---C--|----C-|-----C`.

Comment: @tomalek Your modified variant still fails on two occurences of C. Face it, as much as you'd like to not have it, you need the ending $ :)

Comment: @Kenneth: Yeah, you're right, that's true for this regex. It's not true for mine, though.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, I did use spaces instead of `[^C]`.

Comment: @KennethJ Of course it's right to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
^(?=[ C]{6}$) *C(?! *C)
```

Explanation:

```
^             # start-of-string
(?=[ C]{6}$)  # followed by exactly 6 times " " or "C" and the end-of-string
 *C           # any number of spaces and a "C"
(?! *C)       # not followed by another C anywhere (negative lookahead)
```

Notes:

- The `^(?=…{6}$)` construct can be used anywhere you want to measure string length but not actually match anything yet.
- Since the end of the string is already checked in the look-ahead, you do not need to put a `$` at the end of the regex, but it does not hurt to do it.

Comment: It shouldn't be ^C, the user asked for a white space.

Comment: +1 for awesome use of lookaheads, interesting example. However, the match fails on two occurences of C, this fixes it: ^(?=.{6}$)[^C]*?C(?!.*C)

Comment: on 2nd inspection, this fails when C is mixed with other characters

Comment: @KennethJ: I've just changed the regex to cater for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
^[^C]*C[^C]*$
```

but this will not verify the length of your string.

Comment: +1 The negative character classes are better than my lookaheads.

Comment: Character classes are better. But this doesn’t take the overall length into account. So you will need to do something like: `^(C[^C]{5}|[^C]C[^C]{4}|[^C]{2}C[^C]{3}|[^C]{3}C[^C]{2}|[^C]{4}C[^C]|[^C]{5}C)$`

Comment: … but unfortunately, with the second requirement (spaces only) this does not work anymore. See @testalino's comment on my answer.

Comment: Solved it, you need to incorporate the length lookahead from Tomalak, and replace [^C]* with whitespace: ^(?=.{6}$) *C *$

Comment: @Gumbo: You're not being serious. I doubt that this will beat look-aheads in performance.

Comment: @Tomalak: Maybe not that one. But maybe this one: `^(C[^C]{5}|[^C](C[^C]{4}|[^C](C[^C]{3}|[^C](C[^C]{2}|[^C](C[^C]|[^C]C)))))$` ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: The point is rather that not every regular expression implementation does support look-aheads assertions.

Comment: @Gumbo, if not every RE implementation supports look-aheads, then every such implementation supports the length of a string. So just to it beside the RE matching...

Comment: @eumiro: We don’t know if the whole string is always the subject. Maybe it’s just a substring.